# Using CD Writing Wizard in .NET project

Tags: vb.net

I'm wanting to burn the contents of a folder to CD from within a VB.net project.
After a few hours of research it doesn't appear as simple as I thought it would.

Is it possible to control the native CD writing wizard on XP\Win7?
All I need to do is add the folder, give the CD a name and start the burn - the Wizard would be ideal and save hours of coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like its what you are looking for (example code included):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/280E8542-B8D1-4501-913C-368E89ABAEF6

Comment: This method does not seem to work on Vista+ - The burning wizard always returns "There are no files in the staging area"

Comment: For vista it looks like you need to do some research on imapi2.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx

Comment: Shame, automating the wizard would have been an ideal solution.

Comment: I attempted to convert that project to VB (compiled the Imapi2Interop.cs as a dll) kind of worked but too many issues to be usable without a high level of C# knowledge.